# Compiling libcurl with Visual Studio (bool undefined)

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

I want to compile curl from source inside a Visual Studio project.

I get this error (and a lot more):

```
curl\src\tool_sdecls.h(67): error C2061: Syntax Error: Identifier'bool' (..\..\..\framework\libs\curl\src\tool_cb_dbg.c)
curl\src\tool_sdecls.h(68): error C2061: Syntax Error: Identifier'bool'is_cd_filename' (..\..\..\framework\libs\curl\src\tool_cb_dbg.c)
curl\src\tool_sdecls.h(68): error C2059: Syntax Error: ';' (..\..\..\framework\libs\curl\src\tool_cb_dbg.c)
```

The source of this file is:

```
65:  struct OutStruct {
66:      char *filename;
67:      bool alloc_filename;
68:      bool is_cd_filename;
69:      bool s_isreg;
...
```

It looks like `bool`is not defined for some reason.
I tried defining `HAVE_BOOL_T` but nothing changed.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I added the folowing to `curl_config.h`

```
//for undefined bool error
#if _MSC_VER > 1700
    #include <stdbool.h>
#else
    #ifndef bool
        typedef int bool;
        #define false 0
        #define true 1
    #endif
#endif

//for warning C4005: 'POLLIN' : macro redefinition error
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
```